# Relative path in IOS (xcode 4)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am now using xcode 4 to build a project that will run on ios simulator. The structure of my files in the disk are as follows:

```
MyProject  // this is a folder
   ViewController.h
   ViewController.mm
MyProject.xcodeproj
abc.txt
```

In ViewController.mm file, I want to read abc.txt, I try to read the file in this way:

```
std::string str("abc.txt");


    std::fstream fFid(str);
    if(fFid.is_open())
    {

        NSLog(@"open file succeed");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Fail to open");
    }
```

However, it seems that it does not work. Any ideas on reading the text file? Thanks.

Comment: did I just read _Xcode4_?

Comment: Be aware that if you plan on releasing you app on the AppStore Apple requires you to use Xcode 5 and the iOS 7 SDK.

Comment: So are you creating a full-fledged iOS App?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Comment: [get application directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11800545/programmatically-get-the-name-of-the-application-folder-in-osx)

Comment: Have you added the file to the project? Only then it is copied to the bundle. (In my opinon: before you do that you should move abc.txt into the MyProject/ directory)